# Block access at folders starting with ~ and all of their folders/files

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, wildcard

**EDIT: The reason of my problem is mod_userdir. So if your host has enabled mod_userdir like Hostgator reseller package for example http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/apache-htaccess/mod_userdir then be sure that you host can disable this. Apparently Hostgator refused to disable this for the specific hosting package**

Recently I received a phishing warning from google related to a file that doesn't exist in my server. The reason that it appears as it is hosted on my server is because I'm on a shared/reseller Apache hosting package. So I discovered that I can access any file of another website which is hosted on the same server as my site if I know the username of the owner of the website.

Meaning I can access

```
http://mywebsite.com/~somebodyelsesusername/any_path_to_their_files.php
```

Well this behavior is undesirable, so I want to deny access to other's websites through my domain using .htaccess

How can I block every **root folder** for instance mydomain.com/~somefolder/ starting with ~ without knowing what follows next? Of course I have to block access to any files or folders of that folder. I tried

```
<DirectoryMatch "^\~|\/\~">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

But I guess I'm not doing it right.

The answer below answers in fact the question however it doesn't fix my problem due to special circumstances. So I marked it as correct and I will further investigate the issue

Comment: Errr; I would suggest that this problem is fixed through the hosting company instead, because your site can therefore also be accessed through someone else their domain. That will eventually cause duplicate content penalties in google.

Comment: I think you are right and I have contacted the hosting company HG for this. However I think that blocking access to my files through other domains is a different question and it might be easier, I'm working on it now, otherwise I should ask a separate question if I can't do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<DirectoryMatch>` can only be used in the server configuration file, or virtual host context, not through .htaccess.

You can possibly block access using mod_rewrite. Make sure the module is enabled, then use the following directives:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^~ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Yes mod_rewrite is enabled but the solution doesn't work

Comment: Do you have any other rules? In that case puting this on top might help. If not, can you test if you are allowed to rewrite by trying `RewriteRule ^foo /bar [L]` and going to `yoursite.com/foo`. It should tell you that /bar does not exist on this server. I thought that `~` could be matched without a problem, but I might be mistaken. I can't test it here though.

Comment: Update: I have created a root folder ~somefolder and tried to access that folder http://mywebsite.com/~somefolder/ and I get a 403 code, so your answer works, However this doesn't work for http://mywebsite.com/~somebodyelsesusername/ so that leaves me unable to do anything right?

Comment: I am guessing the .htaccess file is never read for those requests in that case. You can easily test this by adding bogus in your .htaccess file and requesting those pages. It should serve an internal server error for any page that uses that .htaccess file. If the file is never read, then you can't solve the problem through .htaccess. You likely don't have access to the main configuration file, as it is a shared hosting setup.

Comment: Yes I tested it and nothing in the htaccess file is considered when accessing those folders. Your answer is correct though and answers the question, although it doesn't fix my problem. Should I mark it as an answer and ask a separate question or modify the existing question and wait for more answers?